# Numeric results for integrals involving double Fourier transform

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I am interested numerically calculating the following integral (it's rather unstable):
$$
    U(p,q)= \frac{2}{\pi} \frac{1}{p q} \int_0^{\infty} \sin(pr) \sin(qr) V(r) dr 
$$
$V(r)$ is some function with the behavior:
$$
\lim_{r\to 0^+} V(r)=\infty\;\;\text{and}\;\;\lim_{r\to \infty} V(r)=0
$$
And of course it has to go to zero fast enough for the integral to converge, for example
$$V(r)= \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-r}}{r}$$

In fact the above $V(r)$ has a nice analytic solution for testing:
$$
\frac{1}{pq}\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-r}}{r} \sin (p r) \sin (q r) \, dr=\frac{1}{4pq}
\left[\ln \left((p+q)^2+1\right)-\ln \left((p-q)^2+1\right)\right]
$$

In general $U(p,q)$ is unstable. One thing I have tried to help this for large $p$ and $q$ is to WLOG let $p>q$ and $b=\frac{q}{p}$ then under the variable transformation $x=pr$ we have:
$$
    U(p,q)= \frac{2}{\pi} \frac{1}{p^{2}q} \int_0^{\infty}\sin{(x)}\sin{(bx)} V\left( \frac{x}{p} \right) dx
$$

This helps with numeric stability, but not enough! I am still getting unstable results for pretty much every method.It was suggested in passing to me that I use a fast Fourier transform, but I'm not sure if that is actually useful.

What techniques can I use to help make this integral more numerically stable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can compute Fourier transform of $V(|r|)$ then $U(p,q)$ can be rather simply expressed in terms of it:
$$
\int_0^\infty \sin pr \sin qr V(r) dr = 
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{2}\left[
\cos (p-q) r - \cos (p+q) r
\right] V(r) dr = \\ =
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \cos ((p-q) r)
V(r) dr 
-
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \cos ((p+q) r)
V(r) dr = \\ =
\frac{1}{4} 
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos ((p-q) r)
V(|r|) dr 
-
\frac{1}{4}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos ((p+q) r)
V(|r|) dr.
$$
And thus
$$
U(p, q) = \frac{\hat V(p-q) - \hat V(p+q)}{2\pi p q}
$$
where
$$
\hat V(s) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty V(r) e^{isr} dr.
$$

Comment: Very nice. I like this approach.

Comment: Using this in combination with an FFT solves my problem. Thanks!